# How do I use Stan to fit a covariance matrix?

Tags: bayesian, stan, wishart-distribution

I'm new to Stan (and bayesian methods in general), so this is likely very simple.

I'm trying to model some multivariate normal data. All I want to know is the covariance matrix generating the data, assuming the data is centered. I've been using this as my template: https://github.com/jrnold/pygments_bugs/blob/53eecb07aa805df7cedc365b7faab641e8fe541d/examples/stan/jaws.stan

But I can't get it to properly fit a known covariance matrix.

I'm using Matlab to simulate some data. Here's the little code snippet:

```
x = mvnrnd([0,0],[1,1.5;1.5,3],100);

data = struct('N',100,...
'dim',2,...
'x',x);

fit1 = stan('file','singleWishart.stan','data',data,'iter',1000,'chains',4);`
```

And here's the stan code:

```
data {
int<lower=0> N; // Sample size
int<lower=1> dim; // Number of dimensions
row_vector[dim] x[N]; // Value for each sample on each dimension
}

parameters {
cov_matrix[dim] cov1;
}

model {
vector[dim] zeros; //For now, means are zero
matrix[dim,dim] identity; //Identity for scaling matrix

zeros <- rep_vector(0, dim);
identity <- diag_matrix(rep_vector(1.0,dim)); 

cov1 ~ inv_wishart(dim, identity);

for (n in 1:N)
    x[N] ~ multi_normal_prec(zeros, cov1);
}
```

I've tried both cov1 ~ inv_wishart and cov1 ~ wishart (I'm not clear on which one I should be using - I thought wishart, but the examples I've seen seem to use inv_wishart), but neither have worked, giving me ridiculous estimates instead of the expected 1, 1.5, 1.5, 3.

Comment: You should declare and define `zeros` and `identity` in a `transformed data` block of a .stan program so that they only get allocated once at the outset rather than every time the posterior function is evaluated (which could be more than a million times with the default settings).

Answer (score 8):

The primary reason that your code does not yield the expected answer is that you are using the `multi_normal_prec` likelihood rather than the `multi_normal` likelihood. The former expects a *precision* matrix (the inverse of a covariance matrix) as its second argument, while the latter expects a covariance matrix.

For what it is worth, you should be able to recover the matrix that generated the data if you use `multi_normal_prec` for the likelihood, use `cov1 ~ wishart(dim, identity)` for the prior, and then inspect the distribution of the *inverse* of `cov1`. But it would be more straightforward, to change the likelihood to `multi_normal` and leave `cov1 ~ inv_wishart(dim,identity)` as is.

Comment: All that said, I do not ever use the Wishart or inverse-Wishart distributions with Stan for reasons given at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/stan-users/fhghq6Rxbqs/-dG0apK0NV4J . If you must utilize the inverse-Wishart, to get decent results from Stan I would integrate it out of the posterior as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution#Conjugate_distribution .

Comment: For the benefit of OP, I'd like to add that using a parameterization that separates the variances from correlations is superior in Stan because it allows each to move separately, which is important because Stan cares about the geometry of the posterior.